# Select the nth element without doing it recursively in scss

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

Having the following structure:

```css
    .parent-label {
      display: flex;
      flex: wrap;
      flex-direction: column;
      background-color: red;
      :nth-of-type(2) {
        background-color: green;
        padding-left: 30px;
      }
      .child-label {
         background-color: yellow;
         display: flex;
         flex-direction: column;
         justify-content: center;
         margin-top: 20px;
         margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent-label">
   <div class="child-label">child
   </div>
   <div class="child-label">
     <div>
        <span>test</span>
        <a href="test">click</a>
     </div>
     <div>
        <span>test</span>
        <a href="test">click</a>
     </div>
     <div>
        <span>test</span>
        <a href="test">click</a>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

There is a `parent-label` div which contains 2 `child-label` divs.

I don't know why isn't the styling of child-label not working, it should have yellow background, or the `nth-of-type` should be green.

What is wrong?

Comment: .child-label selector should not be inside the .parent-label selector. Move out the .child-label selector and it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS selectors have been misplaced. The `:nth-of-type(2)` selector and the `.child-label` selector should not be nested inside the `.parent-label` selector.

The below CSS should solve your problem:

```
.parent-label {
  display: flex;
  flex: wrap;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;

}

.child-label:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: green;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

.child-label {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

JS Fiddle Link : https://jsfiddle.net/cf3hkvtn/

**NOTE**: Please make sure you check all the syntax issues before posting questions in SO.

Answer (score 1):

You have written the wrong structure of SCSS add :nth-of-type(2) in the `.child-label` CSS please check the below code. Hope it will work for you.

```
.parent-label {
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
     flex-direction: column;
     background-color: red;

    .child-label {
     background-color: yellow;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
     margin-top: 20px;
     margin-bottom: 20px;

        &:nth-of-type(2) {
            background-color: green;
            padding-left: 30px;
        }
    }
}
```